# What is the best way to create a search facility for static content in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I've built a static website using Symfony 2.6, it has been translated into 8 different languages and includes several forms.

It now requires a search facility, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What means a static content ? Simple html pages?

Comment: How can you use forms if the website is static? Do you handle the forms without PHP?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru yes simple html in twig templates

Comment: @A.L There is some dynamic functionality on the site but most of it is static templates http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search facility can be gained using:

- Special database requests, in mysql `SELECT * FROM article WHERE article.body LIKE '%searched_query%'`
- Full text search can be achieved using tools like:

  - [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
  - [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

  But in both cases you should save your content in database or other files.
- *In your case as workaround I suggest to crawl your own site and return links from sites where you found the searched text sort of this stuff*

  ```
  use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

  class InternalCrawler {

      private $crawler;
      private $textToSearch;
      private $matchedUrls;

      public function __construct($textToSearch)
      {
          $this->textToSearch = $textToSearch;
      }

      protected function requestUrl($url)
      {
          //curl the url to crawl
          //...

          return $html;
      }

      protected function getUrlsToCrawl()
      {
          return array(
              'url-to-homepage',
              'url-to-an-article-page',
              ...
          );
      }

      protected function match($url, $html)
      {
          $this->crawler = new Crawler($html);
          $textExists = $this->crawler->filter("html:contains('{$this->textToSearch}')")->count();
          if ($textExists) {
              $this->matchedUrls[] = $url;
          }
      }

      public function getMatchedUrls()
      {
           foreach ($this->getUrlsToCrawl() as $url) {
               $html = $this->requestUrl($url);
               $this->match($url, $html);
           }

           return $this->matchedUrls;
      }
  }
  ```

As a result you will have the list of `urls` that matched your searched text.

Comment: Using DOMCrawler to index the content was the resolution I came to as well, thanks Alexandru.


In my searches I did come across the following jQuery plugin (not ideal I know) http://www.tipue.com/search